# Unable to run a saved Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, cognos-tm1

I am new to python, I have a sample python script which runs successfully from a new notebook in Jupyter. When the script is saved and re-opened it fails with name error.

Below sample script:

```
import paramiko
from TM1py import TM1Service

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname = "sftp.xxxxx.com",username  = 'Test user', password = 'abcd', port=22)
sftp_client = ssh.open_sftp()
sftp_client.get(source,dest)
sftp_client.close()
ssh.close()
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(hostname = 'sftp-xxxxxx.com',username  = 'Test user', password = 'abcd',port = 22)
sftp_client = ssh.open_sftp()
sftp_client.put(source,dest)    
sftp_client.close()
ssh.close()
```

Comment: what error message do you get?

Comment: can you include the full error in your question?

Comment: Jupyter Notebook uses a kernel. If you declared (say) variables `source` and `dest` in the notebook at some point and then deleted them, then they would exist in the Jupyter Notebook running kernel, but if you restarted the kernel (or saved the code to a script), they would not exist.

Comment: Thank you everyone , seems like issue is with kernel . I have deleted the notebook and saved the script in a new notebook. Saving the script in new notebook fixed the issue.